# Using downloaded gensim instance with minimal RAM usage

Tags: python, memory-management

I am working on gensim for natural language processing application. I want to use downloaded instance with minimal RAM usage.

```
import gensim.downloader as api
corpus = api.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-300')
```

This is the code snippet. Is there any way we can minimize the RAM usage in python script itself?

Comment: Load a smaller model? What's the current memory usage of your script? What's your target? Have you run memory profiling?

Comment: I ran memory profiler. RAM usage is more than 90% of the total memory. The model is smaller. Is there any way I can bring it to 60-65%?